# How to take fade class off from bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my application even after modal is closed , backdrop of the modal is sticking to the screen even after the modal is hidden. I guess it is due to fade class. Can anyone please suggest, how to handle this, I have tried with

```
target.appendJavaScript("$('#"+modal.getMarkupId()+"').modal({backdrop:false});");
```

on button submit but its not working. Please suggest.

Comment: How are you closing the modal? Are you using Bootstrap's `modal('close')`?

Comment: if you close your modal by using javascript :modal('hide'); it will fade out the backdrop

Comment: I am using modal.appendCloseDialogJavaScript(target);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Remove `fade` from the class

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true">
  ...
</div>
```

## [REFERENCE](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-remove-animation)

Comment: I have not given any class for that modal. I am using it as, <div wicket:id="myModal"></div>

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for it, if someone facing similar kind of issue, they can use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( "div" ).removeClass( "modal-backdrop" );
</script>
```

that solved my problem.